# Bash - Deleting a line from file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

Probably a pretty straight forward one but I'm fairly new to bash
I'm trying to delete a line from a .txt file that contains a specific string. The string is specified as a variable "$logline"

My code for sed is currently:

```
logline="example2"
sed -i "/$logline/d" > /root/file.txt
```

The contents of the `/root/file.txt` file is...

```
/root/Dir/example.txt
/root/Dir2/example2.txt
/root/Dir/example3.html
...
```

I expect just the line `/root/Dir2/example2.txt` to be deleted.

However when I run this the entire txt file is getting wiped, and I get the error message `sed: no input files`.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message like `sed: no input files` or `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`? If so, it's helpful to add that to the question.

Comment: Hi
Yes along with wiping the txt file it is also finishing by saying "sed: no input files"
I have researched this for hours and tried many variations of the argument format but can't get it working correctly.

Comment: Remove `>` from command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -i` has no output, so when you redirect to a file it will just be truncated.

Instead, give the filename to sed directly without redirecting:

```
sed -i "/$logline/d" /root/file.txt
```

Comment: Hi
I've just attempted this change but now I'm just getting the error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Comment: @William This means that `$logline` is empty

Comment: I've tried adding a new line 

echo $logline

This outputs what i would expect as "/root/testDir" as an example
but still shows the error from sed..

Comment: `//root/testDir/d` is not a valid sed command. You can use `sed -i "\\@$logline@d"` to allow using `/` but not `@` in `$logline`. You can avoid such escaping/injection problems by using `grep -F` instead of `sed` as suggested in the other answer

Comment: Cool. That seems to have done the trick ! I'm totally new to bash so thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If your variable `$logline` contains **exact text to be matched**, sed is probably the wrong program to be using.  Pattern addresses are regular expressions, and you'll need to escape any of the metacharacters understood in basic REs, including `\`, `*` and `.`.

For removing a fixed string, you'll probably find it easier to use `grep -Fv`; something like

```
grep -Fv -- "$logline" <"$file" >"$file.new"; mv "$file.new" "$file"
```

If you really must use sed, you should choose whether you're editing in-place with `-i` or using standard output - you don't get both.  So either

- ```
  sed -i "/$logline/d" "$file"
  ```
- ```
  sed "/$logline/d" "$file" >"$file.new" && mv "$file.new" "$file"
  ```

Comment: I'm new to bash so will probably look into this also for learning purposes. However the slight change in code from the other answer has sorted it and seems to be working.
Thanks for your help